TortoiseHG merge subrepositories correctly
In the latest THG, if I create a new branch feature in SubRepositoryA, SubRepositoryB, and commit the changes to ParentRepository, then add some changes to SubRepositoryA, but not SubRepositoryB, and commit the changes to ParentRepository, so that everything is commited, and feature has changes only in SubRepositoryA committed, when I merge back into default, assuming that no other work is done for SubRepositoryB in default, it doesn't create a merge commit in SubRepositoryB, meaning that SubRepositoryB will have the wrong commit as the HEAD for that merge.
Can I get mercurial or THG to always create a merge commit in both subrepos?
e.g.
Expected:
           Parent             ||        SubRepositoryA         ||    SubRepositoryB
                              ||                               ||
default__...______merge<-HEAD || default__...______merge<-HEAD || default__<-HEAD
       \_feature_/            ||        \_feature_/            ||        \_feature

